# Using multiple External JARs in Spring Boot Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-data

I have an external JAR of a Spring Boot project with package `com.abc.external`, and my main Spring Boot project with package `com.code.main`. 
I want to include classes (bean) from `com.abc.external` in `com.code.main` main function. I am doing it the following way.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.external", "com.code.main" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.abc.external", "com.code.main" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.external", "com.code.main" })
public class App {
    //code
}
```

If I import the `com.abc.external` project into Eclipse, then the external base package is getting identified. However, if I just have the dependency in `POM.xml`, it is not getting identified. The JAR is present in the lib folder.

What should I do to use an external JAR package along with my original one in the Spring Boot project?

Comment: please attach peice of code your pom.xml. And how are you  started you application by maven console or in eclipse???

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the jar from the lib folder into your local maven repository in order for it to be available to maven and subsequently eclipse.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

In your case the command would be something like:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/<jar-name> -DgroupId=com.abc -DartifactId=external -Dversion=<your-version> -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then update your Eclipse classpath with `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
Alternatively you could deploy your com.abc.external jar to a maven repository and reference it from there.